# error C2181: недопустимый else без парного if

Tags: c

Начал изучать Visual C++ по Пахомову (самоучитель). В процессе отладки кода выходит ошибка error C2181: недопустимый else без парного if.
Код:

```
// 11.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>     //для getchar(), putchar()
#include <conio.h>     //для getch()
#define eof -1         //признак конца файла

#define yes 1          //для придания значения переменной in
#define no 0           //для придания значения переменной in

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int c;             //для ввода символа
    int nc;            //для подсчета количества введенных символов
    int nl;            //счетчик строк
    int nw;            //счетчик слов
    int in;            /*флажок слежения за тем, находится ли в данный
                       момент программа внутри слова или нет*/
    nc=nl=nw=0;        //обнуление счетчиков
    in=no;             //до ввода находимся вне слова
    printf ("Enter your strings and press the key <Enter> >\n");
    while ((c=getchar()) !=eof)
    {
        if (c != '\n') //если символ - не конец строки
            nc++;      /*какой бы символ не ввели
                       (кроме CTRL+z и '\n'), его надо учитывать в счетчике*/
        else           //иначе... (если введенный символ - конец стоки)
            nl++;      /*Здесь c=='\n' и поэтому сколько раз нажали <Enter>,
                       столько будет и строк*/
    if (c==' ' || c=='\n' || c=='\t') /*если символ хотя бы один из
                                          in=no;*/
      /*сколько бы раз ни нажимали на клавиши "пробел", "конец строки", "табуля-
      ция", всегда будем находиться вне слова*/
    else if(in==no) /*сюда попадаем только тогда. когда нажали любую клавишу,
                         кроме пробела, <Enter> и конца строки*/
        {
            in=yes; /*если до этого мы были вне слова (in==no), то
                    сейчас попали на начало слова*/
            nw++;   //и слово надо учесть в счетчике
        }
        else        //иначе... если (in != no)
            ;       /*эта часть выполняется, когда мы, находясь внутри слова (in
        !=no), ввели любой символ, кроме пробела, знака табуляции и знака конца
        строки. В этом случае подсчет слов не ведется, а программа возвращается
        на ввод следующего символа*/
    }               //закрывающая скобка оператора while()
    printf ("Strings.....=%d\n",nl);
    printf ("Words......=%d\n",nw);
    printf ("Characters..=%d\n",nc);
    _getch(); /* Вводит символ, но без эхо-сопровождения (задерживает ото-
              бражение результатов расчетов на экране)*/
} //закрывающая скобка функции main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Синтаксис `if/else`

```
if (условие) statement else statement
```

Ни первый statement, ни второй statement (если присутствует `else`) нельзя опустить. Они должны присутствовать.

У вас в

```
if (c==' ' || c=='\n' || c=='\t') /*если символ хотя бы один из
                                      in=no;*/
  /*сколько бы раз ни нажимали на клавиши "пробел", "конец строки", "табуля-
  ция", всегда будем находиться вне слова*/
else 
  ...
```

отсутствует первый statement (комментарий не является statement).

Если вы по какой-то причине пока хотите оставить первый statement пустым, то нужно хотя бы поместить туда пустой statement

```
if (c==' ' || c=='\n' || c=='\t') 
  /* комментарий */
  ; 
else 
  ...
```

Т.е. просто `;`, или, если вам так больше нравится, в качестве пустого statement вы можете использовать `{}`.

P.S. Однако возникает вопрос: почему у вас `in=no;` оказалось внутри комментария? Это так и задумано?

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало. А в книге то знака нет.

Comment: @MrSibdes: Так а почему у вас `in=no;` оказалось внутри комментария? Это так в книге?

Comment: Да так написано, я думаю это сделано в целях лучшего объяснения строки кода.

Comment: /*если символ хотя бы один из in=no;*/ - объясняет строку if (c==' ' || c=='\n' || c=='\t'). настоящий in=no выведен отдельной строкой. Пахомов так написал код)